# Finding $a,b$ in this limit without using L’Hôpital’s rule

Tags: limits

> Assume that $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{16^x-16x^4}{a^x-2x^b} =32.$$ Find the value of $a+b$.

**My attempts.** In order to have this limit a number we should have a zero in the denomiter at point $1$ which immediatly implies $a=2$. Then writing $16^x-16x^4=(2^x)^4-(2x)^4=32(2^x-2x)$ at point $1$ will leave us with $$\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{2^x-2x}{2^x-2x^b}=1.$$ Using L’Hôpital’s rule in this case gives us $$1=\lim_{x \to 1} \frac{\ln(2)2^x-2}{\ln(2)2^x-2bx^{b-1}} \Rightarrow b=1.$$

I am interested to see a solution without L’Hôpital’s rule (because L’Hôpital’s rule isn’t allowed in our school).

Comment: Would it not suffice to note that $2^x - 2x = 2^x - 2x^b$ if $b=1$? This is an obvious equality by inspection and then you simply have the limit as $x \to 1$ of $1$, which is obviously $1$, so the limit indeed still holds.

Comment: @Eevee Trainer Yes it is enough but I need a method to show that anything other than $1$ won't work.

Comment: @EeveeTrainer That only shows that $b=1$ _works_. Not that $b$ is necessarily $1$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set $x-1=h$

$$F=\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{16^{1+h}-16(1+h)^4}{a^{1+h}-2(1+h)^b}$$

$$=16\cdot\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{16^h-16-h(4+O(h))}{a(a^h-1)-2\left((1+h)^b-1\right)+a-2}$$

Divide numerator & denominator by $h\ne0$ as $h\to0$

$$F=16\cdot\dfrac{\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{16^h-1}h-\lim_{h\to0}(4+O(h))}{a\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{a^h-1}h-2\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(1+h)^b-1}h+\dfrac{a-2}h}$$

$a-2$ must be $0$ for the existence of the limit

$$F=16\cdot\dfrac{\ln16-4}{a\ln a-2b}=16\cdot\dfrac{4\ln2-4}{2\ln2-2b}$$

$\implies b=1$

Comment: Haven't you used L'Hopita's in the end?

Comment: @TahaAkbari, Are your talking about $$\lim_{h\to0}\dfrac{(1+h)^b-1}h$$ which can manged using https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_series as well

Comment: Thank you.Do you see anything wrong in my solution above?Since it implies $b=1$.

Comment: @TahaAkbari, Sorry I don't see any mistake there. Do you find one here?

Comment: I am not so skilled in Binomial series so I can't say exactly.

Comment: @TahaAkbari, $$16^x=2^{4x}$$ in general $$\ne32\cdot2^x$$

Comment: I used $a^4-b^4=(a-b)(a^3+a^2b+ab^2+b^3)$ and then put the limit of the nonzero term.

Comment: and $b=1$ works according to wolfram alpha see:https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=+lim_%7Bx+%5Cto+1%7D%5Cfrac%7B16%5Ex-16x%5E4%7D%7B2%5Ex-2x%7D

Comment: @labbhattacharjee, in the first line of your proof, the numerator of your fraction should read $16^{1+h}-16(1+h)^4$ rather than $16^{1+h}-16(1+h)^2$; this will yield the correct value $b=1$.

Comment: @A.J., Thanks a lot.

Comment: @TahaAkbari, Please  find the updated post

Answer (score 1):

First off, if $a\ne2$, then the denominator hasn't limit $0$, so we need $a=2$. Now you can write
$$
\frac{16^x-16x^4}{x-1}=\frac{16^x-16}{x-1}-16\frac{x^4-1}{x-1}
$$
Similarly,
$$
\frac{2^x-2x^b}{x-1}=\frac{2^x-2}{x-1}-2\frac{x^b-1}{x-1}
$$
Using only known limits we get
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{16^x-16x^4}{x-1}=16\log16-16\cdot4=64(\log2-1)
$$
and
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{2^x-2x^b}{x-1}=2\log2-2b=2(\log 2-b)
$$
Hence we need $\log2\ne b$ in order that the limit is finite, because
$$
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{16^x-16x^4}{2^x-2x^b}=
\lim_{x\to1}\frac{\cfrac{16^x-16x^4}{x-1}}{\cfrac{2^x-2x^b}{x-1}}=\frac{64(\log2-1)}{2(\log2-b)}
$$

Comment: How do you compute limit of $\frac{16^x-16}{x-1}$ when $x$ tends to $1$?

Comment: @TahaAkbari You can write $x=1+h$ and the limit becomes that of $16\frac{16^h-1}{h}$ for $h\to0$. Since $16^h=e^{h\log16}$, do another substitution to reduce to the limit of $\frac{e^h-1}{h}$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $$a-2=\lim_{x\to 1}a^x-2x^b=\lim_{x\to 1}(16^x-16x^4)\cdot\dfrac{1}{\dfrac{16^x-16x^4}{a^x-2x^b}}=0\cdot\frac {1}{32}=0$$ and hence $a=2$.

Using this value of $a$ we get $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{16^x-16x^4}{2^x-2x^b}=32$$ or $$\lim_{x\to 1}\frac{16^{x-1}-x^4}{2^{x-1}-x^b}=4$$ or $$\lim_{x\to 1}\dfrac{\dfrac{16^{x-1}-1}{x-1}-\dfrac{x^4-1}{x-1}}{\dfrac{2^{x-1}-1}{x-1}-\dfrac{x^b-1}{x-1}}=4$$ or $$\frac{4(\log 2-1)}{\log 2 - b} =4$$ so that $b=1$ and hence $a+b=3$.